# Whmcs Payumoney Payment Error after a successful payment

Tags: whmcs

Whmcs is not changing payment status after successful payment. Payment is successful from the payment gateway but it is still showing unpaid status. I checked the gateway error log and I found this error each time payment is processed. Please check below error

error => Salt could not be fetched from CO. Reason: Cant proceed request at this time.

Answer (score 1):

Just Remove the "service_provider= payu_paisa" from your form page/integration
issue will get resolved.

Comment: I'm facing same issue for my client website but this solution saves my day, thanks @dhruv